# Styling HTML in a JEditorPane or JTextPane

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I want to display HTML in a JEditorPane or JTextPane, but I want the style (font size) to come from the Look and Feel.  Is there a way to do this, or do you have to use embedded HTML styling?

Here is an example:

```
epText = new JEditorPane("text/html", content);

StyleSheet ss = ((HTMLEditorKit)epText.getEditorKit()).getStyleSheet();
ss.addRule("p {font-size:" + FontManager.getManager().getFontSize() + "}");
HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) epText.getEditorKit();
kit.setStyleSheet(ss);

epText.setEditorKit(kit);
```

Whenever I set the editor kit, all text disappears.  Do I need to set the text everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Dig into this snippet, from the Java API for [HTMLEditorKit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html):

> Customization from current LAF
>
> HTML provides a well known set of features without exactly specifying
>   the display characteristics. Swing has
>   a theme mechanism for its
>   look-and-feel implementations. It is
>   desirable for the look-and-feel to
>   feed display characteristics into the
>   HTML views. An user with poor vision
>   for example would want high contrast
>   and larger than typical fonts.
>
> The support for this is provided by the `StyleSheet` class. The
>   presentation of the HTML can be
>   heavily influenced by the setting of
>   the StyleSheet property on the EditorKit.

**Edit:** when you set the Editor Kit, it de-installs the old kit and installs the new one. This changes the underlying model, which is why the text 'disappears'.
[Read the API for more info](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setEditorKit%28javax.swing.text.EditorKit%29).

But you may not need to re-create the entire kit... just add a new sheet to your style.

Answer (score 0):

Call this from the `main` method after you set L&F.

```
public static void setDefaultStyle()
{
    // looks like WTF but that is the way to set default CSS
    StyleSheet sheet=new HTMLEditorKit().getStyleSheet();
    // add your rules
    sheet.addRule("...");
    sheet.addRule("...");
}
```

**EDIT:** At least this should work for `JTextPane`.